# App Hangs while Scaling Bitmap in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw

Drawing text on `Bitmap`

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    m_paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    m_paint.setColor(textColor);
    m_paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    int width = (int) ( m_paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f);  // round
    float baseline = (int) (- m_paint.ascent() + 0.5f); // ascent() is negative
    int height = (int) (baseline +  m_paint.descent() + 0.5f);         
    final  Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    canvas1.setBitmap(image);
    canvas1.drawText(text, 0, baseline, m_paint);        
    return image;
}
```

Step 2- Drawing Canvas

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    if (CustomTextview.GetDB().size() != 0) {
        for (CustomTextview textview : CustomTextview.GetDB()) {
            scale = textview.GETSCALE();
          final  Bitmap bitmap= textAsBitmap(textview.text,textview.size*scale,textview.color);
            if (bitmap!=null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, textview.X, textview.Y, textview.paint);
      }       
    }
    canvas.restore();

}
```

I am using scale listener to  scale the bitmap.but when ever scale,it hangs after 5 to 10 mins..

Comment: What is "Bitmap b= Bitmap.createBitmap(image);" for? Instead of "b" just use "image"

Comment: That is not working.the background gives blur effect  while using direct canvas

Comment: @pskink now check the Question.i have edited..

Comment: what is textAsBitmap for? why dont you draw text using Canvas api?

Comment: can u draw Text without bitmap canvas?

Comment: Yes, read Canvas API

Comment: If it gets stuck, most likely your for loop runs forever or has many iterations

Comment: The problem may be in the CustomTextview code. Could you post this? But as others point out Canvas.drawText() would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw text on the Canvas directly without having to create a bitmap first.

To do that, create a Paint with the right configuration, calculate how big your text will be when it is drawn and then draw the text itself directly onto the canvas.

```
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setTextSize(30f);


String myText = "This is a test";
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
textPaint.getTextBounds(myText, 0, myText.length(), bounds);

canvas.drawText(myText, 0, myText.length() rect.width()/2, rect.height()/2, textPaint);
```

The code above will draw the text centered, but you can easily change this to fit your own needs.

Comment: that also hangs.when you draw Text Size is larger

Comment: At what line does it actually hang? Also I don't really see why you should call `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()`. Can you remove those calls?

Comment: I don't think that is creating problem?

Comment: When ever I enlarge the text. It's hangs

Comment: @jmlos understand the problem.its not about drawing the text.it hangs when its large

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

inside of application in your AndroidMenifest.xml. such as

```
<application
           android:largeHeap="true" >
</application>
```

Hopefully works properly. Thanks

Comment: sorry i dont want to try this one.its not recommend to use also

Answer (score 0):

The reason it hangs is probably because creating a lot of bitmaps that way will quickly cause out of memory.
If you really need a bitmap you can create a single bitmap and reuse it instead. Better is probably as other suggested solution to use canvas api directly. You can even use a single instance of Paint to avoid memory overhead.

Comment: .I am drawing multiple text .i have treid canvas api also.i dont know it also hangs.i checked while using canvas.there is no memory error.the Gpu got struck in some point while i zoomin and zoom out

Comment: I think this is the right solution check in your logcat if you see some references to a memory leak.

Comment: I have checked is there any way to reuse the bitmap?

Comment: Create it once and have it as a member of your class.